# FreeType error: FT_Load_Char returns 36

Tags: c++, c, freetype

I've been trying to get FreeType working in my game, but it doesn't seem to work whenever I try to load the characters from a font. I've looked at a bunch of tutorials on the web and as far as I can see there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code.

I've tried with different fonts but they produce the same error.

This is the code that fails:

```
int errorCode = FT_New_Face(freetype, filename.c_str(), 0, &face);
if (errorCode != 0)
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to load font: " << filename << ". Error code: " << errorCode << std::endl;
}

for (char i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    errorCode = FT_Load_Char(face, i, FT_LOAD_RENDER); // This returns 36 when i is 0
    if (errorCode != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << filename << ": Failed to load character '" << i << "'. Error code: " << errorCode << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This prints out:

> FreeSans.ttf: Failed to load character ' '. Error code: 36

I looked up error code 36 in the FreeType headers and it appears to be "Invalid_Size_Handle". This confounds me since no size handles where passed in the function. The only size handle I can think of the the face->size property, but there shouldn't be anything wrong with it since the face struct was initialized in the FT_New_Face function.

And yes, I do initialize FreeType earlier on in the code.

So, does anybody know what I am doing wrong and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: i shoudl be cast to an FT_ULONG

Comment: I tried that, same result.

Comment: Don't cast it, but instantiate the object with that type.  Casting a 1 byte value to an 8 byte value isn't correct

Comment: Tried that aswell, and I get the same result...

Comment: Why do you think that the typeface contains information for the NUL character (and what information would that be? no width, no outline). You can always check if the typeface contains a character by calling `FT_Get_Char_Index`.

Comment: @OmriBarel Finally some progress! (even though I'm still stuck!) Now on the other hand, every character I try to test with FT_Get_Char_Index returns 0. I'm guessing that the issue lies with the way I load the fonts.

Answer (score 4):

I got that same error code once. I guess the "Invalid_Size_Handle" means that the *font size* instead of memory size setting is invalid.

I fixed the problem by adding a call to **FT_Set_Char_Size** right after **FT_New_Face**. Hope that can be of help.

Answer (score 3):

try to set font size after loading the face:

```
int errorCode = FT_New_Face(freetype, filename.c_str(), 0, &face);
if (!errorCode)
    std::cerr << "Failed to load font: " << filename << ". Error code: " << errorCode << std::endl;

int pensize = 64;
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, pensize, 0);

// you can now load the glyphs
```

hope it helps!